# JsTree Open first Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jstree

I'm using JStree plugin to create a tree, my question is if there is any option or way to show the first child of a list.

For instance, i got a list with 5 children  and some children has other childrens, in my case i just want to show the first children of each

.

There is my code

html list

```
<ul id="tree">
```

Item 1

Item 2

Folder 1

- Sub Item 1.1
- Sub Item 1.2
- Sub Folder

  - test
  - SubFolder

    - Third Child
    - Third Child
    - Third Child

Item 3

Folder 2

- Sub Item 2.1
- Folder 2.1

  - Sub Item 2.1.1
  - Sub Item 2.1.2

Item 4

an here my js

```
    $(function() {
        $("#tree").treeview({
            collapsed: true,
            animated: "medium",
            control:"#sidetreecontrol",
            persist: "location"
        });
    })
```

Comment: Could you provide working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in this plugin you cant do that, i fixed it using css:

```
ul li ul {display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do that, so I placed an Id in each li and after I used this code:

```
$("#my-tree-view").jstree("open_node", $("#id-first-li"));
```